# How to unzip a zip file using scala?

Tags: excel, scala, unzip

Basically I need to unzip a .zip file which contains a folder called modeled which in turn contains a number of excel files.

I have had some luck in finding code that was already written (ZipArchive) which is meant to unzip the zip file, but I cannot figure out why it throws an error message when I use it. The code for ZipArchive and the error message are listed below:

```
import java.io.{OutputStream, InputStream, File, FileOutputStream}
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipFile}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object ZipArchive {

  val BUFSIZE = 4096
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](BUFSIZE)

  def unZip(source: String, targetFolder: String) = {
    val zipFile = new ZipFile(source)

    unzipAllFile(zipFile.entries.toList, getZipEntryInputStream(zipFile)_, new File(targetFolder))
  }

  def getZipEntryInputStream(zipFile: ZipFile)(entry: ZipEntry) = zipFile.getInputStream(entry)

  def unzipAllFile(entryList: List[ZipEntry], inputGetter: (ZipEntry) => InputStream, targetFolder: File): Boolean = {

    entryList match {
      case entry :: entries =>

        if (entry.isDirectory)
          new File(targetFolder, entry.getName).mkdirs
        else
          saveFile(inputGetter(entry), new FileOutputStream(new File(targetFolder, entry.getName)))

        unzipAllFile(entries, inputGetter, targetFolder)
      case _ =>
        true
    }
  }

  def saveFile(fis: InputStream, fos: OutputStream) = {
    writeToFile(bufferReader(fis)_, fos)
    fis.close
    fos.close
  }

  def bufferReader(fis: InputStream)(buffer: Array[Byte]) = (fis.read(buffer), buffer)

  def writeToFile(reader: (Array[Byte]) => Tuple2[Int, Array[Byte]], fos: OutputStream): Boolean = {
    val (length, data) = reader(buffer)
    if (length >= 0) {
      fos.write(data, 0, length)
      writeToFile(reader, fos)
    } else
      true
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/oepTemp/modeled/EQ_US_2_NULL_('CA')_ALL_ELT_IL_EQ_US.xlsx (No such file or directory), took 6.406 sec
[error]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
[error]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
[error]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
[error]     at com.contract.testing.ZipArchive$.unzipAllFile(ZipArchive.scala:28)
[error]     at com.contract.testing.ZipArchive$.unZip(ZipArchive.scala:15)
[error]     at com.contract.testing.OepStepDefinitions$$anonfun$1.apply$mcZ$sp(OepStepDefinitions.scala:175)
[error]     at com.contract.testing.OepStepDefinitions$$anonfun$1.apply(OepStepDefinitions.scala:150)
[error]     at com.contract.testing.OepStepDefinitions$$anonfun$1.apply(OepStepDefinitions.scala:150)
[error]     at cucumber.api.scala.ScalaDsl$StepBody$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ScalaDsl.scala:61)
[error]     at cucumber.api.scala.ScalaDsl$StepBody$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ScalaDsl.scala:61)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.scala.ScalaStepDefinition.execute(ScalaStepDefinition.scala:71)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:298)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:48)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
[error]     at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
[error]     ...
```

So based on the error message it looks like it's trying to find the exported excel file? This part completely throws me off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've added below how I'm calling the method, perhaps I'm doing something silly. Also I'm up for using a different way to extract my zip file if you can recommend one.

```
val tempDirectoryDir = "src/test/resources/oepTemp/"
ZipArchive.unZip(tempDirectoryDir + "Sub Region Input - Output.zip", tempDirectoryDir)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well since were are using some utilities from java, here is a version basen on [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/), translated to scala, maybe this should be more functional, but it is useful

```
package zip

import java.io.{ IOException, FileOutputStream, FileInputStream, File }
import java.util.zip.{ ZipEntry, ZipInputStream }

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 04/06/15.
 */
object Unzip extends App {

  val INPUT_ZIP_FILE: String = "src/main/resources/my-zip.zip";
  val OUTPUT_FOLDER: String = "src/main/resources/my-zip";

  def unZipIt(zipFile: String, outputFolder: String): Unit = {

    val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)

    try {

      //output directory
      val folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
      if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
      }

      //zip file content
      val zis: ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
      //get the zipped file list entry
      var ze: ZipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

      while (ze != null) {

        val fileName = ze.getName();
        val newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

        System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        //create folders
        new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

        val fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

        var len: Int = zis.read(buffer);

        while (len > 0) {

          fos.write(buffer, 0, len)
          len = zis.read(buffer)
        }

        fos.close()
        ze = zis.getNextEntry()
      }

      zis.closeEntry()
      zis.close()

    } catch {
      case e: IOException => println("exception caught: " + e.getMessage)
    }

  }

  Unzip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE, OUTPUT_FOLDER)

}
```

Answer (score 30):

Here's a more functional and precise way doing this

```
import java.io.{FileInputStream, FileOutputStream}
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
val fis = new FileInputStream("htl.zip")
val zis = new ZipInputStream(fis)
Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach{ file =>
    val fout = new FileOutputStream(file.getName)
    val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
    Stream.continually(zis.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(fout.write(buffer, 0, _))
}
```

Comment: Stream is now deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

Trying to work with Tian-Liang's solution, I realized that its not working for zips with a directory structure. So I adopted it this way:

```
  import java.io.{FileOutputStream, InputStream}
  import java.nio.file.Path
  import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream

  def unzip(zipFile: InputStream, destination: Path): Unit = {
    val zis = new ZipInputStream(zipFile)

    Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).foreach { file =>
      if (!file.isDirectory) {
        val outPath = destination.resolve(file.getName)
        val outPathParent = outPath.getParent
        if (!outPathParent.toFile.exists()) {
          outPathParent.toFile.mkdirs()
        }

        val outFile = outPath.toFile
        val out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)
        val buffer = new Array[Byte](4096)
        Stream.continually(zis.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(out.write(buffer, 0, _))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just curious, is it ok not to close the FileOutputStream object?

Comment: After some years I would assume that you are right. It will always be more safe to close any output stream. :)

Answer (score 7):

Late to the game here, but I would take advantage of `scala.collection.JavaConverters` to get a for-loop over the zip file entries, and `java.nio.Files` to get simple copying and directory creation:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}
import java.util.zip.ZipFile
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def unzip(zipPath: Path, outputPath: Path): Unit = {
  val zipFile = new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile)
  for (entry <- zipFile.entries.asScala) {
    val path = outputPath.resolve(entry.getName)
    if (entry.isDirectory) {
      Files.createDirectories(path)
    } else {
      Files.createDirectories(path.getParent)
      Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(entry), path)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scala.util.Try

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def using[T <: { def close() }, U](resource: T)(block: T => U): U = {
  try {
    block(resource)
  } finally {
    if (resource != null) {
        resource.close()
    }
  }
}

def processZipFile(zipFile: ZipFile)(doStuff: ZipEntry => Unit) {
  using(new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile))) { zipInputStream =>
    val entries = Stream.continually(Try(zipInputStream.getNextEntry()).getOrElse(null))
        .takeWhile(_ != null) // while not EOF and not corrupted
        .foreach(doStuff)
        .force
  }
}
```

Comment: The _Try_ is a nice touch; so this was useful to me.  However, _map_ would feed the following _force_, where the greedy _foreach_ leaves nothing for _force_ to work on.

Comment: For the record for other readers: the _Try_ allows processing to continue if there's a "bad" file embedded in the stream.  Not sure if that's a real problem; still - this presents some ways to manage error cases without dropping the entirety of the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I would merge the automatic calling of ZipFile.close() into Steve's answer. It is made by the using method which is present in Noel Yap's answer.

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}
import java.util.zip.ZipFile
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

def using[T <: {def close()}, U](resource: T)(block: T => U): U = {
  try {
    block(resource)
  } finally {
    if (resource != null) {
      resource.close()
    }
  }
}

def unzip(zipPath: Path, outputPath: Path): Unit = {
  using(new ZipFile(zipPath.toFile)) { zipFile =>
    for (entry <- zipFile.entries.asScala) {
      val path = outputPath.resolve(entry.getName)
      if (entry.isDirectory) {
        Files.createDirectories(path)
      } else {
        Files.createDirectories(path.getParent)
        Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(entry), path)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked ChatGPT and it doesn't give me a good answer. In case people still need an updated answer and ChatGPT may crawl this page, I paste the answer here. I use [os-lib](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/os-lib) to manage directories since I feel it's more intuitive.

```scala
  def unzip(input: String, output: String) = {
    val fis = new FileInputStream(input)
    val zis = new ZipInputStream(fis)
    Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry).takeWhile(_ != null).filter(!_.isDirectory).foreach { file =>
      val path = os.pwd / os.RelPath(output) / os.RelPath(file.getName)
      os.makeDir.all(path / os.up)
      val fout = new FileOutputStream(path.toIO)
      val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
      Stream.continually(zis.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(fout.write(buffer, 0, _))
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's for scala 2.12, I use this version for Spark.