# Executing unzip command programmatically

Tags: linux, scala, zip

I have created  a shell script and inside of it is a simple statement `unzip -o $1` and on running through terminal and passing a .zip file as parameter it works fine and takes `5` second to create unzipped folder.Now I am trying to do the same thing in scala and my code is as below :

```
object ZipExt extends App {

  val process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("/home/administrator/test.sh", "/home/administrator/MyZipFile_0.8.6.3.zip"))
  process.waitFor

  println("done")
}
```

Now whenever I am trying to execute ZipExt it gets stuck in `process.waitFor` forever and `print` statement is not reached.I have tried using this code both locally and on server also. I tried other possibilites also like creating local variable inside shellscript, including exit statements inside shell script, trying to unzip other `.zip` other than mines, even sometimes `print` statement is executing but no unzipped file is created there. So I am pretty sure there is something wrong about executing `unzip` command programmatically to unzip a file or there is some other way around to unzip a zipped file programtically.I have been stuck with this problem for like 2 days, so somebody plz help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have given us appears to be insufficient to reproduce the problem:

```
% mkdir 34088099
% cd 34088099 
% mkdir junk
% touch junk/a junk/b junk/c
% zip -r junk.zip junk
updating: junk/ (stored 0%)
  adding: junk/a (stored 0%)
  adding: junk/b (stored 0%)
  adding: junk/c (stored 0%)
% rm -r junk
% echo 'unzip -o $1' > test.sh
% chmod +x test.sh
% scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val process = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("./test.sh", "junk.zip"))
process: Process = java.lang.UNIXProcess@35432107

scala> process.waitFor
res0: Int = 0

scala> :quit
% ls junk 
a  b  c
```

I would suggest trying this same reproduction on your own machine. If it succeeds for you too, then start systematically reducing the differences between the succeeding case and the failing case, a step at a time. This will help narrow down what the possible causes are.

Comment: Sorry I was AFK, will try it ASAP

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: no instead of using `unzip` inside shell command I programatically now unzipped the `.zip` file

Comment: lol @Seth Tisue , check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640627/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-scala