# Get list of files from a folder inside a packaged project

Tags: scala, package

I have a list of public assets inside the "src/main/resources" folder that looks like this:

public/images/

- asd1.png
- asd2.png

I'm trying to list all the files inside the "public/images/" directory, as it is a compiled project using `sbt universal:packageBin` I'm trying to access the assets using:

```
val input = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/public/images/")
```

or

```
val input = getClass.getResource("/public/images/")
```

`getResourceAsStream` returns an empty result and `getResource` returns a URL object that contains a direct path to the folder but I cannot list anything inside that folder even with `new File(getClass.getResource("/public/images/"))` as the check for `.isDirectory()` returns a `false` as a response or `.listFiles()` throws an exception.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640627/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-scala

Comment: the resources are already loaded inside the class path so unziping a jar thats already loaded seems waistfull

Comment: Does `listFiles` throw an exception, or does it simply return `null`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin it throws a null pointer as it's not a directory and file doesnt exist, the `new File(getClass.getResource("/public/images/"))` deosnt see whats inside the JAR, I did manage to get it working with "new JarFile()" approach but thats loading a jar as a new resources and scanning whats inside, which is waistfull as the resources are already loaded inside the classpath so logically there should be a way to list these resources or even list all resources inside the already loaded jar